# Is it valid to nest CSS rules?

Tags: css, syntax, stylesheet

Is this valid CSS syntax?

```
li:hover{
  css rules ...
  span {
    css rules ...
  }
}
```

It works, but I'm not sure if it's valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't nest CSS rules like that. If you want to select span elements inside hovered li elements you need to write two seperate rules:

```
li:hover{
  /* CSS */
}
li:hover span{
  /* CSS */
}
```

Unless you're using [less](http://lesscss.org) for which you can nest rules, and it will compile into regular CSS.